# Heater core failed for the second time

Tags: volvo, coolant-leak, 850, heater-core

I have Volvo 850 and the heater core is leaking... again. The same thing happened 3 or 4 years ago.

Is there some design issue that is causing this to happen repeatedly? If so, any long-term fix?

Comment: Possibly electrolysis,  you can test the coolant for it or have it done at a shop.

Comment: What is the cause of the leak? Corrosion? Then internal (which will be coolant related) or external ( which means something has got on to it) or has it been punctured? Screw etc??

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the recommended coolant fluid? Did you mix coolants of different colors? Coolant formulations differ greatly.

The engine coolant fluid has to be changed periodically (usually, 2 years for the old green one and 5 years for the long life ones), otherwise its additives degrade and they no longer perform as they were originally meant to.